# Passing user input from bash to PHP

Tags: php, bash

For example, I have this bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php

<?php

  $options = ['Option 1', 'Option 2'];

  echo "Please choose an option:\n";

  foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' - ' . $value . "\n";
  }

  shell_exec('read OPTION');
```

Is there a way to get `OPTION` value and pass it to PHP environment?

Comment: You should take a look at this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php this will help you with what you want.

Comment: you want the user to input something? Why bother starting a shell for that? you can use fgets() and the like to read from stdin already.

Comment: [readline](http://php.net/readline)?

Comment: I have such things like request from PHP to BASH and back to PHP. I was thinking to give answer but no idea how you want so check then i can answer it accordingly. 1. Pass ajax request 2.$command = exec("<bash command>", $output, $return_var);  foreach ($output as $outputFound) { echo $outputFound; (php output) } 3. Get output from shell (Java script output) and repeat for various options.

Comment: You can't read the environment of a subproc, but you can read the output. So read VAR && echo $VAR should work. If the shell is long running then open the subshell with popen and read from it as needed.